Particular reshape of pandas dataframe
How can I create a new dataframe if the input looks like this:
inputTable = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'B' : [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'C' : [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
})

and the resulting table should look like this:
resultingTable = pd.DataFrame({
    'Category' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
    'Value'    : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
})

I am aware of pd.wide_to_long() but it seems to be an overkill for the simple case I am dealing with. Is there something more appropriate and, perhaps, more efficient?
There is also a pd.melt() solution as explained in one of the replies, with more details here. However, this is not the only solution, as the other reply suggests.

Why are the here proposed solutions not enough for you? Are they not enough efficient for your purposes?

Use pd.melt with var_name = "Category" and value_name = "Value":
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "B": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "C": [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})

df2 = pd.melt(df, var_name="Category", value_name="Value")

print(df2)

Output:
   Category  Value
0         A      1
1         A      2
2         A      3
3         A      4
4         A      5
5         B      2
6         B      3
7         B      4
8         B      5
9         B      6
10        C      3
11        C      4
12        C      5
13        C      6
14        C      7


A possible solution, which uses stack:
(inputTable.stack().reset_index(1)
 .set_axis(['Category', 'Value'], axis=1)
 .reset_index(drop=True))

Output:
   Category  Value
0         A      1
1         B      2
2         C      3
3         A      2
4         B      3
5         C      4
6         A      3
7         B      4
8         C      5
9         A      4
10        B      5
11        C      6
12        A      5
13        B      6
14        C      7

